# Get the descriptions of product details in the script by BeautifulSoup and json

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm getting descriptions of product details in the  tag from the web.

Here's the code :

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url  = 'https://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=599211032&rrec=true&mlink=5050,12413545,onproduct1_rr_3&clink=12413545#pdp-page-content'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('script', id="pdpData").string
jsData = re.search(r'window.__ PRODUCT_PAGE_STATE __\s+=\s+', results)
data = json.loads(jsData.group(0))
```

and the part xxxxx I want is below in the script

```
window. __PRODUCT_PAGE_STATE __ = JSON.parse(xxxxx)
```

Through `re.search` to find `window. __PRODUCT_PAGE_STATE __` , I still can not reach the part xxxxx.

Is there any other way to extract the info in the part xxxxx?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/product.do?pid=599211032&rrec=true&mlink' \
      '=5050,12413545,onproduct1_rr_3&clink=12413545#pdp-page-content'

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url).content,
    "html.parser",
).find('script', id="pdpData")

the_xxx_part = json.loads(
    re.search(r"\.parse\((.+)\);", soup.string, re.S).group(1).strip(),
)
print(json.loads(the_xxx_part)["productData"]["name"])
```

Output:

```
Unisex Faux-Fur-Trim Hooded Frost-Free Puffer Jacket for Toddler
```

To print the entire `JOSN` object edit this:

```
print(json.loads(the_xxx_part)["productData"]["name"])
```

into this:

```
print(json.loads(the_xxx_part))
```

Comment: This is literally the webpage's `title` which can be got using BS alone, the question is to get `description on product details tab`?

Comment: @Ananth the output is just to illustrate that the *ENTIRE* content of the script has been properly loaded into a JSON object and can be access via the keys. Print out `the_xxx_part` to see everything else.